# Getting .htaccess redirects from one domain to another to work for WWW ( both http://www. and https://www.), HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a scenario for redirection I'm having trouble wrapping my head around.

The goals are:

- old-domain.com/store needs to redirect to new-domain.com/store
- There are three validation scripts that should remain on Old-Domain.com
- Everything else from old-domain.com to redirect to new-domain.com
- These rules need to apply to all scenarios HTTP, HTTPS and WWW (HTTP and HTTPS)

The problem I'm having is that the old-domain.com/store only properly redirects to new-domain.com/store when I remove the WWW redirects. I can't seem to get it to all play together nicely.

Here's what I've got:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
## Rewrite rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old-domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://old-domain.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old-domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://old-domain.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/validation-script-1\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/validation-script-2\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/validation-script-3\.html
Redirect 301 /store/ https://new-domain.com/store
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new-domain.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

We've also tried the following but then the validation scripts stop passing through:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
## Rewrite rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/validation-script-1\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/validation-script-2\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/validation-script-3\.html

# Remove trailing slash from non-filepath urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ http://old-domain.com/%1 [R=301,L]

# Include trailing slash on directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://old-domain.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?store https://new-domain.com/store [R=301,L]

# Remove WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new-domain.com/ [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Your conditions are a bit confusing. I'm able to redirect all request to new-domain. You want to redirect only validation-script or every URL other than validation-script

Comment: I'd like to not redirect any of the validation scripts at all. I'd like to redirect all traffic that hits ald-domain.com/store to new-domain.com/store/ then I'd like to redirect all other traffic hitting old-domain.com to new-domain.com. Does that help at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following rewrite rule will redirect all (www.)old-domain.com URLs to `https://new-domain.com/` except URLs containing validation-script-(1|2|3).html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/validation-script-(1|2|3)\.html$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/new-domain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Check this demo https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=f0deda97-dff8-569e-bd6f-411b8a779361

Edit:
to redirect `old-domain.com/store` or `old-domain.com/store/` to new-`domain.com/pages/store`

```
RewriteRule ^store/?$ "https\:\/\/new-domain\.com\/pages\/store" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you! this is very close. I think I made a mistake in oversimplifying my example .htaccess. Can what you provided act just like it does now, but instead of old-domain.com/store/ going to new-domain.com/store, can you help me get old-domain.com/store/ to redirect to new-domain.com/pages/store?

Comment: @Front_End_Dev If you want to just redirect old-domain.com/store/ to new-domain.com/pages/store and leave rest as it is then you have to add its redirect rule to above the current rule

Comment: We've got that working, but we ran into an issue we ran into in the beginning. "/store" isn't redirecting properly, it very specifically needs "/store/" in order to work? is there a way around this?

Comment: I was able to get this working. Thank you very much for all the help!